# How do I calculate percentage of one column in Jooq / SQL in only one transaction?

Tags: sql, jooq

**Question:**

```
Grades Table
---------------
Name    Score 
"Bob"     "A"
"Sally"   "A"
"Joe"     "B"
"Ann"     "C"
```

Suppose I have this table, and I want to calculate what percentage of students have a C. The correct answer would be 25%. How do I do that in **one transaction** in JOOQ (or raw SQL if I must)?  Or is it not possible? Thank you.

**Bad solution: Two Transactions:**

```
float numberOfC = database.fetchCountOfStudentsWithGrade("C");  //Transaction
float numberOfStudents = database.fetchCountOfStudents(); //Transaction
float percentage = numberOfC / numberOfStudents;
```

**Good solution attempt: One Transaction - JOOQ**

```
context.select(val(context.selectCount().from(TABLE1))
          .div(val(context.selectCount().from(TABLE1))))  // This line has error
          .fetch(0, int.class); //One transaction

//Error: Cannot resolve method `div(org.jooq.Param<T>)`
```

**Jooq Docs for Arithmetic Expressions:**

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/arithmetic-expressions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In raw sql, you can do:

```
select avg(case when score = 'C' then 1.0 else 0 end) as c_ratio
from t;
```

The above is standard syntax and should work in all databases.  In some databases, you can write this as:

```
select avg( score = 'C' ) as c_ratio
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using SQL Standard `FILTER (WHERE ..)`

One option in jOOQ would be to use [`AggregateFunction.filterWhere()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/AggregateFilterStep.html#filterWhere-org.jooq.Condition-) as such:

```java
ctx.select(count().filterWhere(T.SCORE.eq("C"))
                  .cast(BigDecimal.class)
                  .div(count()))
   .from(T)
   .fetch();
```

The above is assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

HSQLDB and PostgreSQL have native support for the `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE x)` syntax. In all other databases, jOOQ will emulate this using `COUNT(CASE WHEN x THEN 1 END)`.

#### A note on the approach with correlated subqueries

In your question, you suggested an approach using correlated subqueries that do the `COUNT(*)` calculations. It's almost never a good idea to run several such subqueries if there's a [solution running several aggregations in one step](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/)